# Can't figger out why .contains() doesn't return true, tried everything nothing worked

Tags: java, list, bukkit

I can,t figger out why .contains doesn't return true when List: [NGX-CORE, PingAPI] contains [PingAPI]

Server Plugins returns: [PingAPI, NGX-CORE]
addon.depend returns: [PingAPI]

Contains code: `ServerPlugins.contains(addon.depend)`

Console output: [image]

```
System.out.println("ServerPlugins contents: " + ServerPlugins);
System.out.println("Addon Dependencies: " + addon.depend);
System.out.println("Is addon.depend empty: " + addon.depend.isEmpty());
System.out.println("Does ServerPlugins contain addon.depend: " + ServerPlugins.contains(addon.depend));
System.out.println("Does ServerPlugins contain addon.depend: " + ServerPlugins.contains(addon.depend.toString()));
if (addon.depend.isEmpty()) {
    if (!(m.disabled.contains(addon.name))) {
        Core.Main.m.registerCommands(commands, addon);
        System.out.println("Add-on " + addon.name + " loaded! v" + addon.version);
        addon.onLoad();
        plugins.add(addon);
        m.enabled.add(addon.name);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Add-on " + addon.name + " is disabled and wasn't loaded!");
    }
} else {
    if (ServerPlugins.contains(addon.depend)) {
        if (!(m.disabled.contains(addon.name))) {
            Core.Main.m.registerCommands(commands, addon);
            System.out.println("Add-on " + addon.name + " loaded! v" + addon.version);
            addon.onLoad();
            plugins.add(addon);
            m.enabled.add(addon.name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Add-on " + addon.name + " is disabled and wasn't loaded!");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Add-on " + addon.name + " requires other plugins to function, required plugins: " + addon.depend.toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ServerPlugins is a Collection of Strings, and addon.depend is a String? Or some other type having a proper equals method?

Comment: Both of them are a List<String>

Comment: What is `System.out.println("addon.depend: " + addon.depend.contains()));` meant to do? Contains what? That doesn't look like it's your real code... which begs the question of what else isn't your actual code.

Comment: Ahhh... you need containsAll

Comment: I did some testing I said "I tried everything" you can ignore the "                    System.out.println("addon.depend: " + addon.depend.contains()));" line I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do is: replace `.contains` with `.containsAll`.

`.contains` looks for an Object, but doesn't compare objects. Yet `.containsAll` looks thought a collection.

**Solved thanks to Bram**